# Can you force a desktop browser to respect a viewport meta tag?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, viewport, desktop

I'm trying to do a "desktop view" (*/me shudders*) for a responsive site I'm working on.  The easiest way I've been able to accomplish this is by toggling the width in the viewport meta tag between `device-width` and a `1024px`, based on a cookie.

This works great when I emulate or view in a mobile browser, but if I view the site on a desktop browser and just snap it with `Win + ←` or `Win + →`, the window is resized below a responsive breakpoint and does not respect the contents of the viewport meta tag.

For reference, here is my viewport meta tag:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=yes">`

What I'm wondering, is if there's any way to force the viewport on desktop like you can on mobile devices and tablets.

I've created [a pen that replicates the issue](http://codepen.io/collink/full/PqbRLW/).  If you resize the window you'll see that the `<div>` changes from orange to red at `1023px`.  If you then emulate a mobile device, say in Chrome, or view it from an actual mobile device, the `<div>` will stay orange, because the viewport is fixed at `1024px`, thus never hitting the media query.

You can view the source of the pen here: http://codepen.io/collink/pen/PqbRLW

Comment: @AliGajani like the CSS3 transform scale()?

Comment: I don't think that will help.  I'm using the fixed-width viewport to circumvent media queries (all of my media queries start at max-width: 1023px), so I don't think scale will get around that.

Comment: @AliGajani Check my edit to the original post.  I've added an example.

Comment: if you're doing responsive design correctly, **every view is desktop view**. That is to say, desktop users will be able to see all sizes. A simple trick that helps avoid poor RWD choices is to name your breakpoints "small" "medium" and "large" and correct anyone who says "mobile" "tablet" and "desktop".

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Just to understand this better

Comment: @AliGajani I don't WANT to do it.  It's a requirement of the product.

Comment: @zzzzBov trust me, I'm of that opinion as well.  I've fought this kicking and screaming the whole way...but this is something that is being required of me and my team.

Comment: I don't understand the problem, sorry. Can you explain again? The display changes when the browser window is made narrower, because of the media query, yes? But it shouldn't change, right? Then just get rid of the media query!

Comment: I believe IE can do that using `-ms-viewport{width:800px}` css query

Comment: The meta name=viewport is currently only supported on mobile devices, however it's specification will be added for all browsers, including desktop browsers, in a future CSS release: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-device-adapt-1/

Comment: Your CSS includes ``@media screen and (max-width: 1023px)``.  That is known as _adaptive_ design, not _responsive_ design.    Responsive design doesn't use @media tests, and is a much better idea than adaptive design.  Perhaps some of your problems are caused by confusion between adaptive and responsive?